# PHP writing CSV, outputting the entire webpage for some reason

Tags: php, csv, filesystems

```
function outputCSV($data) {
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler){
        fputcsv($filehandler, $vals, ',', '"');
    }
    array_walk($data, '__outputCSV', $outstream);
    fclose($outstream);
}


function someFunctionInTheBigPHPFile() {
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    $mydata = array(
    array('data11', 'data12', 'data13'),
    array('data21', 'data22', 'data23'),
    array('data31', 'data32', 'data23'));

    outputCSV($mydata);
    exit;
}
```

The output CSV does contain the data array. The problem is, this array is displayed along with the rest of the webpage, that is everything before this function is called and everything that comes after it, despite these two functions being the only ones that deal with any fopen and writing to files.

How can I stop the rest of the webpage from interfering? I only want the data array in the CSV..

EDIT: I managed to chop off everything succeeding my array by adding exit;, but I still have the problem of the entire website being displayed before the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of the PHP file, check straight away if you want to print your CSV (this is probably passed through $_POST or $_GET). If so, run it straight through the function and end that function with an exit;.

This prevents anything from happening before or after the CSV is created. For some reason all code on the page is included in the new file, even if the file stream was opened and closed at times independant of when the page's content was computed.

And this effectively leaves you with only what you wanted, not the rubbish before or after it.

Answer (score 1):

Stop execution after outputting the CSV data. You can do this with `die()` or `exit()`.

Comment: Yep I got that half of the job, what about everything before the CSV output?

Comment: Make sure you don't output anything before if CSV is requested.

Comment: I can't really control that, I'm using WordPress and their tables to call a bulk action function. Lots is already happening before this, in a large system that I don't want to edit.

Comment: Oh wordpress, you need to hook into the `parse_request` and render only what you need.

Comment: I'm which case you're hooking your plug in in the wrong place. I suggest you add the WordPress bit, and how you're hooking in the plug in (which action) to your question.

Comment: I'm not hooking it wrong, that's why I'm not asking about that. I'm using the WP_List_Table standard function process_bulk_action() as it's supposed to be used. The table cannot be created or loaded until the rest of the WordPress background is, as it uses functions from those external files, and that already places such residue that I'm looking to delete before my array - that can't be controlled, the table requires it's parents.. I'm just asking if there's a way to clear or overwrite all of the rubbish before I output my array

Comment: You can, with the `parse_request` action hook.

Comment: Hmm they don't have any documentation for that http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/parse_request :( - How would I know which bulk action they're using though, because within the WP_List_Table it's referred to as $this->current_action(), how could I retrieve that before the rest of the world happens?

Comment: Wait found it in the source, $_REQUEST['action'] and $_REQUEST['action2'], I'll look into the parse_request thingy

Comment: Didn't even need that, just had to check $_REQUEST['action'] at the beginning, if it was to export a CSV then just run the function. Somehow the get_option() function still worked, I guess it preloads all of the functions. I feel so stupid..

Comment: Don't, the wordpress execution flow is not the easiest to understand and work with.

Comment: Yeah just thought it much more complicated than it were, didn't need to hook anything at all...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i misunderstood you, but someFunctionInTheBigPHPFile() prints out the file to the screen. So, why are you using this i you dont want to a screen output ?

Comment: I don't know about that, a CSV file is created as expected when this runs. It has the array formatted nicely in CSV style at the bottom (as I want), however with the entire website and everything that happened in it before that (still in the new CSV file), despite me never wanting to add that.